# Link to missing page on https://stackmod.blog/

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, blog-overflow

The company-owned blog https://stackmod.blog/ shows a link to a no-longer-available page

[image]

As far as I know, Blog Overflow doesn't exist anymore. 
I think the link should therefore be removed or updated to point to another fitting page.